# google map in sap.m.dialog sapui5

Tags: dialog, popup, maps, sapui5

I am calling a popup in my view (to show a map with some details) with the following code called EditDialog.fragment.xml

```
<core:FragmentDefinition
  xmlns="sap.m"
 xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.sap.com/sapui5/extension/sap.ui.core.CustomData/1">

 <Dialog
title="Edit Client Location"
class="sapUiPopupWithPadding" >

<VBox fitContainer="true" justifyContent="Center" alignItems="Center">  
    <HBox id="map_canvas" fitContainer="true" justifyContent="Center" alignItems="Center" />  
</VBox>
```

Within my controller I have the following code

```
    if (!this.Edit) {
        this.Edit = sap.ui.xmlfragment("motherclocker." + Edit
                + "Dialog", this // associate controller with the
        // fragment
        );
        this.getView().addDependent(this.Edit);
    }

    this.geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var mapOptions = {
        center : new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397,
                150.644),
        zoom : 15,
        mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(this.Edit.getView().byId(
            "map_canvas").getDomRef(), mapOptions);     

    this.Edit.open();
```

Now the issue is I get the message **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getDomRef' of undefined** . Normally for googlemaps  you just use this.getView() and it works just fine as I have used it in a normal view. I then tried

```
    map = new google.maps.Map(
            this.Edit.getId("map_canvas"), mapOptions)
```

This creates the map object but when the dialog is called; it is not shown.

Anyone know a solution for this? Otherwise I will have to call a new view.

Answer (score 1):

You can access Dialogs using [sap.ui.getCore.byId](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.Core.html#byId) method e.g.:

```
sap.ui.getCore().byId("map_canvas")
```

Dialogs are not part of the usual View but they are added "on top of it". That is why you cannot refer to them through the view.

Regards,
Kimmo